# How to trace the content $this->getChildHtml() inside head.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, magento-1, debug

I am in head.phtml file and need to change the content of `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` as there is no name inside `getChildHtml()`, i don't know thow to look in layout file then.

I almost opened all files in active theme but didn't find the google script that i want to update.

I found a similar question here [same question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33673/how-can-a-block-render-without-specifying-as-property-of-the-block-when-we-us)
but not understood how to trace.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, when there's no block name passed as an argument, all the child blocks get renderer.

If you check `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php` you'll find the following details of this method:

```
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
{
    if ($name === '') {
        if ($sorted) {
            $children = array();
            foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $childName) {
                $children[$childName] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childName);
            }
        } else {
            $children = $this->getChild();
        }
        $out = '';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
        }
        return $out;
    } else {
        return $this->_getChildHtml($name, $useCache);
    }
}
```

So if you wanna find out the list of blocks rendered you can modify the following piece of code:

```
    $out = '';
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
    }
    return $out;
```

And add the following to it:

```
    $out = '';
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($this->getNameInLayout() == "head") {
            Mage::log($child->getBlockAlias());
        }
        $out .= $this->_getChildHtml($child->getBlockAlias(), $useCache);
    }
    return $out;
```

Thanks to this modification, you'll be able to find the list of all block aliases rendered in your `head.phtml` by looking at the `var/log/system.log` file (ensure logging is enabled)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge.I did what you suggested, in system.log i found  2017-04-28T05:38:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): js_cookies
2017-04-28T05:38:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): optional_zip_countries
2017-04-28T05:38:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): google_analytics

Comment: but the script which i am searching is coming from a module phtml file , which i just found.

Comment: Still i want to learn the method you suggested to find the path . Can you please help.

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan if you want to find the template path then just enable the template hints and check the templates in the head.

Comment: i know template path hint . "To find the list of all block aliases" by using above function. As you suggested

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan yes that's what's my code is doing. Gives you all the block aliases in the log file